# How can resolve path webpack with yarn workspace

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

- node_modules

  - react
  - react-dom
  - extenal-react-library
- packages

  - A

    - node_modules

      - react
      - react-dom
    - package.json
  - B
  - C
- package.json

### A

```
//package.json
"dependencies": {
  "react": "~16.8.6"
  "react-dom": ~16.8.6 
}
```

### root package.json

```
//package.json
"dependencies": {
  "react": "^16.8.1",
  "react-dom": "^16.8.1",
  "extenal-react-library": "1.0.0"
}
```

### extenal-react-library package.json

```
"peerDependencies": {
  "react": "~16.8.6"
  "react-dom": ~16.8.6 
}
```

in A packages component, i use `extenal-react-library`
`import { Button } from 'extenal-react-library'`
but, invalid hook call warning https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html

because `import React from 'react'` in `extenal-react-library/Button`
it use in root node_modules/react not A/node_modules/react

Specifically, this only happens on ssr.

help me plz..

Answer (score 0):

It's a well known issue in yarn@1. In yarn@2, this won't happen, but only if you configure it right, as pointed out by the author [in this long thread discussing this very bug](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/7572#issuecomment-753517717).

A quick-fix however is to just add `react` and `react-dom` as dependencies to the root as well (or any other package), because `yarn` will only hoist dependencies to the root, if more than one project use it.